# hawtio ってなんて読むんですか？

Tags: java, monitoring

WebベースのJVM監視ツールhawtioですが、なんと読めばいいのでしょうか。
http://hawt.io

Comment: なんでこの質問が -1 モデレートされたのかよく分からないのですが、StackOverflow に質問を投稿してみれば分かりますが、StackOverflow 自体は自分の質問に自己回答することで、知識を Q&A 形式で共有することを推奨しています。-1 モデレートに何か別の理由があれば、それをコメントしてください。 https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: この質問に「オフトピック」票を投じている方がいますが、この質問は「プログラマーがよく使うソフトウェアに関する問題」の範疇だと思います。
https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
あるソフトウェアを正式になんと呼べばいいのか、という問題は、ソフトウェア開発の切実な問題の1つではないですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

あえてカタカナにすれば、「ホゥート・アイオー」もしくは「ハゥート・アイオー」です。

Youtube や vimeo に hawtio のデモやプレゼンがたくさんあるので、それらを観ればどう発音すればいいか分かります。
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bxgk9--_WzE
https://vimeo.com/141917680